# CodeIgniter: failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Tags: php, codeigniter, require

i am having a

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: require_once(/../scraper_utilities.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Filename: utility_classes/special_price_process.php

Line Number: 3
```

I only have just included a file scraper_utilities.php by this:

```
require_once('/../scraper_utilities.php');
```

Here is the file system of the codeigniter i am currently using:

[image]

EDIT: I Also tried

```
 require_once('../scraper_utilities.php');
```

And

```
require_once(__DIR__.'/scraper_ci/application/libraries/scraper_utilities.php');
```

but didn't also worked.

Comment: why you loading library ?? instead of loading view??

Comment: One often runs into this error, and to quickly troubleshoot it, follow these steps : http://stackoverflow.com/a/36577021/2873507

Answer (score 3):

i solved it by using APPPATH

```
require_once(APPPATH.'libraries/scraper_utilities.php');
```

Comment: There is now a troubleshooting checklist for this frequent error here : stackoverflow.com/a/36577021/2873507

Answer (score 1):

Remove that first / so:

```
require_once('../scraper_utilities.php');
```

../ will take you up one directory, the initial / takes you all the way up to the root directory

Answer (score 0):

Use APPPATH to locate your file in your project. In codeigniter you are not allowed to go back in directory instead you will need to use APPPATH which will give you the application root directory.

In your case it's gonna be like.

```
require_once(APPPATH.'utility_classes/special_price_process.php');
```